# How can we know PK and FK relation if we have 200 tables in a database of SQL Server. Is there any query to check it

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apart from database architecture diagram, is there any way to get the list of all the tables with PK/FK relations?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to inspect the system catalog views - try this for instance:

```
SELECT
    BaseTable = t.name,
    ForeignKeyConstraint = fk.name,
    ReferencedTable = ref.name
FROM
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables ref ON fk.referenced_object_id = ref.object_id
```

This will list the "base" tables, the name of the foreign key constraint, and the referenced table - here from the `AdventureWorks` sample database:

| BaseTable | ForeignKeyConstraint | ReferencedTable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SalesTerritoryHistory | FK_SalesTerritoryHistory_SalesPerson_BusinessEntityID | SalesPerson |
| Store | FK_Store_SalesPerson_SalesPersonID | SalesPerson |
| SalesOrderHeader | FK_SalesOrderHeader_SalesPerson_SalesPersonID | SalesPerson |
| SalesPersonQuotaHistory | FK_SalesPersonQuotaHistory_SalesPerson_BusinessEntityID | SalesPerson |
| ProductModelIllustration | FK_ProductModelIllustration_Illustration_IllustrationID | Illustration |
| WorkOrderRouting | FK_WorkOrderRouting_Location_LocationID | Location |
| ProductInventory | FK_ProductInventory_Location_LocationID | Location |

*(and so forth)*

You can extend this by further inspecting the columns involved in those foreign key constraints - check the [official MS documentation on system catalog views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details